# Questioning the meat served at a local restaurant

Tags: food, fda

I ate at a buffet which allowed me to take out my food and the meat supposed to be chicken tandoori. I got a piece of chicken that I thought was a thigh but when I tried to bite into it the bone looked very dark and hard. I examined the meat more closely and it did not resemble chicken. I noticed that there was a section that resembled a ankle bone and socket or knee cap and socket. I got  really ill and put the meat in my freezer. I wanted to know what animal has a bone that resembles a socket? I know it is not chicken. Who can I get to examine this meat/bone and tell me what it is? Health department, FDA or attorney general? My fear is that it is from a large wild animal not FDA approved to eat.

Comment: Question is about identifying cuts of meat, not about the law

Comment: Chicken joints are substantially similar to mammalian joints.  The presence of a socket does not prove or disprove anything about the identity of the meat.  If I were in your shoes I would start with the local health department; I don't think the FDA prohibits the consumption of any category of meat.

Answer (score 2):

The FDA is a federal agency and is not going to be a first investigator for a local food or health issue.

Contact your local city/county health department with your story and ask them how to get the food sample to them; and ask them if they have any health violations on file for the buffet restaurant.

There are urban legends about the meat(s) that have been served at restaurants; see https://www.google.com/search?q=meat%20restaurants%20site%3Asnopes.com

If you did get sick, Google for free legal help in your area and see what your options are. You can also search for a local personal injury lawyer and ask if they are interested in your case.

But you will find that in order to sue in civil court and be compensated, you need to show damages, either emotional or physical, and you may discover that your damages will be limited to the amount of the cost of the buffet. If you did go to the hospital, that could be compensated, but there are no guarantees in civil court, and a lawyer will need to advise you on that.

It's also possible to sue the buffet restaurant in your local small claims court by yourself and without a lawyer; check your county website for details on how to consider doing that.